# Antlr token priority

Tags: java, antlr

I have a rule definition like this:

```
reference: volume':'first_page'-'last_page ;

volume: INTEGER;
first_page: INTEGER;
last_page: INTEGER;

INTEGER: [0-9]+;

FREE_TEXT_WORD: NON_SPACE+;

fragment NON_SPACE : ~[ \r\n\t];
```

Given the input "**168:321-331**", I thought it would match the **reference** rule. But in reality, the whole string is tokenized as a **FREE_TEXT_WORD**.

How can I make the **INTEGER** token take preference over **FREE_TEXT_WORD** in this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ANTLR will always use a longer token over a shorter token, so to correct this situation you must do one of the following things:

1. Make the `FREE_TEXT_WORD` not match more than 3 characters for the input `168:321-331`, e.g. by not allowing it to contain a digit, or possibly removing the rule altogether.

   - You could also change `FREE_TEXT_WORD` to `FREE_TEXT_CHARACTER`. By limiting the rule to only matching a single character, it will never be longer than another token so its priority will be determined by its position in the grammar. You would then need to create a parser rule for words:

     ```
     freeTextWord : FREE_TEXT_CHARACTER+;
     ```
2. Move the `FREE_TEXT_WORD` token into a mode which is not enabled at the point where your input reaches `168:321-331`.

Comment: Could you please comment on how would your suggestion to tokenized by letter work performance-wise? It looks like there could be many more tokens to handle than when using modes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`FREE_TEXT_WORD` in its current form is capturing everything. You need a [non greedy lexer rule](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Wildcard+Operator+and+Nongreedy+Subrules).

Try changing

`FREE_TEXT_WORD: NON_SPACE+;`

to

`FREE_TEXT_WORD: NON_SPACE+?;`.

Comment: -1: This doesn't do what it looks like it's doing. What you've actually done is transformed the rule to `FREE_TEXT_WORD : NON_SPACE;`, which allows the `INTEGER` rule to match the input by forcing the `FREE_TEXT_WORD` rule to *never* match more than one character.

Comment: @280Z28 Thanks for the comment. I was really under impression that it was a greediness issue and my quick test has solved OP's problem thus I submitted an answer. However I bought the book yesterday, so let me digest it for a while. I will keep the answer here and eventually will update it or delete it.